# whats the reason about different execution order between in 16 & 18 of useRef

Tags: reactjs

```
    const refName = useRef();
    const [name, setName] = useState();

    const handleNameChange = useCallback((item) => {
        setName(item);
        refName.current = item;
        console.log(111)
    }, [])

    console.log(222)
```

the console output is：

```bash
# react 16.8:
222
111


# react 18.2
111
222
```

i do not know the reason，its seems like react scheduling mechanism, i want know about it.
i need write something else pass the stack check.

Answer (score 0):

In v18, React introduced automatic batching of state changes for fewer re-renders of the component.

In v16, React used to re-render the component as soon as a state setter was called.

In your case, as soon as you call `setName(item)`, the component re-renders and gets the new HTML markup. This is when the statement `console.log(222)` is also executed.

Whereas in v18, it waits for all state updates before re-rendering the component. That also means that all statements inside `handleNameChange` will be executed before re-rendering the component.

Hence, the statement `console.log(111)` is executed before `console.log(222)`.

To opt out of this breaking change, React exposed a method `flushSync` using which you can use to force rerender the component on state change.

```js
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

const handleNameChange = useCallback((item) => {
  flushSync(() => {
    setName(item);
  });
   
  refName.current = item;
  console.log(111)
}, []);
```

Ref: https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#automatic-batching